# Android native code profiling

Tags: android, profiling, native

I am trying to profile native android code, but I am getting the
following error.I am running the code on a linux machine.

> $tracedmdump profile   post-processing
>   traces...
>
> Static basic blocks: 64525, Dynamic
>   basic blocks: 87073132
>
> Static instructions: 412004, Dynamic
>   instructions: 509641730
>
> Elapsed seconds: 26.46, simulated
>   instructions/sec: 19.3M
>
> generating dexlist output...
>
> generating dmtrace data...
>
> Error: stack overflow (500 frames)

If anyone knows how to debug this issue...please help

Thanks and Regards,

Bharat Pawar

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328906/android-software-ndk-native-c-code-profiling-on-actual-android-phones

Answer (score 0):

1. From your post and the [Android GIT commitdiff](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/build.git;a=commitdiff;h=05806d7af62e07c6225b2e7103a1b115ecf6c9ad) it looks like this line in the "tracedmdump" shell function went wrong:

   > q2dm -r $ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT/symbols $TRACE $KERNEL $TRACE/dmtrace
2. The q2dm command is part of the [qemu emulator tools](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/development.git;a=tree;f=emulator/qtools;h=65e00b539740ebbef9d11043b903718aa1babe39;hb=1298570eb89eb52172f0c8d8b7ff9ed2511e9225) for Android.
3. Looks like the problem has actually been [fixed and changed source committed](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/development.git;a=commit;h=1298570eb89eb52172f0c8d8b7ff9ed2511e9225).
4. a. If you can, synchronize your local GIT repository with the [Android GIT repository](http://android.git.kernel.org/) and build yourself a more current version of the q2dm tool. 
    b. Alternatively, check/wait for the next NDK (sub-)release for a more current q2dm version.

Hope this helps!