# how to do memory and CPU time profiling in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Android tools and methods work best to find memory/resource leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks)

I want to do memory and CPU time profiling of my Android application. And my application is using C source file also.So I want to do profiling on android level as well as ndk level.As there is Vtune software which is used to do profiling of windows application. Is there any other software like Vtune which will be used to do profiling of android application? Which can show which functions is taking max CPU time and memory. i have used MAT(Memory Analyser Tool) which is showing Memory Leak in my Android application but I am not able to find out where memory leak is happening. Can any body please help to know which tool is very efficient to do profiling of android application.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328906/android-software-ndk-native-c-code-profiling-on-actual-android-phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DDMS http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html, Open it in eclipse and generate a heap dump to view it in Eclipse memory analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

I think MAT is a tool ment for presicely that purpose, if you need help with how to use hpof files and MAT the following liks might be useful,

[MAT link1](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html)

[MAT link2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)

I hope it helps..

Comment: I don't think MAT is for CPU profiling.  It is only for memory usage and leaks identification...