# Native code profiling on Android

Tags: android, native, profiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android software NDK native c code profiling on actual Android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328906/android-software-ndk-native-c-code-profiling-on-actual-android-phones)

The method profiler that comes with DDMS tool doesn't allow Method Profiler for the native codes. Is there any other tool that allows ndk code profiling?